# Deleting a message from protobuf java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to delete a message from protobuf scheme if it isn't used anymore?

Moreover - is it possible to have two versions of the protobuf code, one with the old message and one without it, and they will be able to communicate (deserialize each other objects)?
(of course the old message won't be used by any of them)

Thanks,

Vitali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can delete a message type.

If that message type is used as a field type in any other messages, change those fields to `bytes` instead, which is compatible. You may also want to rename the field to contain the word `obsolete`. I recommend this rather than deleting the field entirely so that no one accidentally reuses the field number for some new field.